# A good way to put together database tables with a few tricky things in the data

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I have data that I need to turn into tables. This data consists of data that mostly concerns the kingdom of the Netherlands, with a few additional countries. This has a few snares:

The kingdom of the Netherlands consists of four countries (one if which is the Netherlands), and three special municipalities, that belong to the Netherlands, but are not in the Netherlands itself.

The Netherlands has provinces, those provinces have municipalities, and municipalities have residences.

The three special municipalities do not belong to any province, they directly belong to the Netherlands.

In the data that we get, the three countries inside the kingdom of the Netherlands are just that; the data shows the country under "country" as well as under "residence"

Then there is the problem of Dutch people in other countries. For those countries, we do not care if they have provinces/municipalities/etc. We just look at that from a country perspective.

To give a better idea, the data we get kind of looks like this:

[image: SampleData]

Bonaire should actually be Country: Netherlands, Municipality: Bonaire (and perhaps Residence: Bonaire, not sure if it will help with querying)

My initial thought how to put this in tables is as follows:

[image: TableStructure]

- Provinces table will have a CountryId
- Municipalities table will have a ProvincesId
- Residences table will have a MunicipalitiesId and a CountryId

The reason the Residences table will also have a CountryId is because of countries like Mexico, of which we don't to want know/show the municipalities, but we do know and want to show the residence.

A problem with this approach though, is that the column for Municipalities in the Residences table will have to contain null values in the case of countries like Mexico.

And yet another problem is that in the case of a country in the kingdom of the Netherlands (except for the Netherlands), the Country as well as the Residence is filled in with the name of the country. I do not know if it is sensible to put the name of the country inside the Residences table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for DB design with these requirements could be:
1) A Dictionary table (id, Name) of geographical object types (may be hierarchical) with records:

`{id = 1, Name = Province},
{id = 2, Name = Municipality},
{id = 3, Name = City}`
, etc

2) A table (id, GeoTypeId, ParentId, CountryId, Name) with FK to itself (ParentId -> Id) that stores links hierarchy of the objects. Records would be:

`{id = 1, GeoTypeId = 1, ParentId = null, CountryId = ..., Name = Zuid-Holland},
{id = 2, GeoTypeId = 2, ParentId = 1, CountryId = ..., Name = Rotterdam}`
.
For Mexico the record would be 
`{id = n, GeoTypeId = 3, ParentId = null, CountryId = ..., Name = Morelia}`

This would be flexible for editing hierarchy, but you'll need some additional effort to select records (that's the price of normalization). You will also be able easily add additional GeoType records when needed for new countries without changing schema.

Comment: And I assume that when I have a special case like a special municipality that I want to put under different GeoTypes, I'd have multiple entries in the Table 2)?

Comment: No, why? For Bonaire the record will be `{id = n, GeoTypeId = 2, ParentId = null, CountryId = ..., Name = Bonaire}`

Comment: Because it might just so happen that the people who will deliver the data want to see Bonaire not only at municipality level (which it is), but as well on another GeoType. Like in the sample excel sheet that I put in my questions. I know, it shouldn't be, but I can't rule out that they might want it like that. And of course, what will I do (or rather, how will I query) when I have to show a summary of everything in the kingdom of the Netherlands?

Comment: @user3488442, I got it. This problem is a problem of data entry, not storage. Initial data must contain information what object belongs to which hierarchy, otherwise without visual validation you won't be even able to say that Mexico is a country, not a 'special case of Netherlands municipality'.So you'll probably have to implement some data validation. I can't come with exact algorithm or even recommendation as it all depends on specific business requirements. If you get initial data in excel sheet, than it will be difficult

Comment: I spoke about it here and your answer was most helpful. Thanks!